# Tips on finding the volume of water in a 3d chess board

Tags: c++, recursion, volume

So I have an assignment where I have to recreate a 3d chessboard that is a RxC grid of squares each being a different height. If the chessboard is water tight, and someone pours water all over it until it can hold no more water, it will hold a fixed amount of water. If the board is already holding its maximum volume of water, any excess water poured onto the board will drain off the edges, there is no tall container surrounding the board. You can assume the squares on the chess board are one inch square, and the heights are given in inches.

```
int CalcContainedWater( const int *p_data, int num_columns, int num_rows )
```

Where `p_data` is a pointer to the first element of a contiguous two-dimensional, row-major array of signed integers. Your function will be tested against a reference implementation for boards of varying shapes and contents to determine its correctness.

Keep in mind the value inside of `p_data` can hold both positive and negative values for the heights.

For example:

A)  The following board yields a containment of 3.

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
```

B) The following board yields a containment of 0.

```
1, 0, 1,
1, 0, 1,
1, 1, 1,
```

C) The following board yields a containment of 1.

```
0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 1,
0, 1, 0,
```

**This is what I have so far :**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <queue>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

enum GridPosition
{
    TOP_LEFT_CORNER,
    TOP_RIGHT_CORNER,
    BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER,
    TOP_ROW,
    BOTTOM_ROW,
    LEFT_COLUMN,
    RIGHT_COLUMN,
    FREE,
};

struct Square
{
    int nHeight;
    int nPos;
    GridPosition gPos;
    bool bIsVisited;
    bool bIsFenced;
    bool bIsFlooding;

    Square(){ nHeight = 0; nPos = 0; gPos = FREE; bIsVisited = false; bIsFenced = false; bIsFlooding = false;};
    ~Square(){};
    Square( int Height, int Pos, GridPosition GridPos, bool Visited, bool Fenced, bool Flooding) 
    { 
        nHeight = Height;
        nPos = Pos;
        gPos = GridPos;
        bIsVisited = Visited;
        bIsFenced = Fenced;
        bIsFlooding = Flooding;
    }
};

template< typename FirstType, typename SecondType >
struct PairComparator 
{
  bool operator()( const pair<FirstType, SecondType>& p1,
    const pair<FirstType, SecondType>& p2 ) const 
    {  
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    }
};

int CalcContainedWater( const int *p_data, int num_columns, int num_rows );

int CalcContainedWater( const int *p_data, int num_columns, int num_rows )
{
    priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, PairComparator<int,int>> qPerimeter;
    queue<pair<int,int>> qFlooding;
    vector<Square> vSquareVec(num_columns * num_rows);

    int nTotalContained = 0;

    int nCurrentSqHeight = 0;
    int nCurrWaterLvl = 0;
    int nDepth = 1;

    for( int nRow = 0; nRow < num_rows; ++nRow)
    {
        for( int nColumn = 0; nColumn < num_columns; ++ nColumn)
        {
            int nCurrArrayPoint = nRow * num_columns + nColumn;
            nCurrentSqHeight = p_data[nCurrArrayPoint];

            Square sSquare(nCurrentSqHeight, nCurrArrayPoint, FREE, false,false,false);

            if(nRow == 0  && nColumn == 0)
                sSquare.gPos = TOP_LEFT_CORNER;
            else if(nRow == 0  && nColumn == num_columns - 1)
                sSquare.gPos = TOP_RIGHT_CORNER;
            else if(nRow == num_rows - 1  && nColumn == 0)
                sSquare.gPos = BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER;
            else if(nRow == num_rows - 1  && nColumn == num_columns - 1)
                sSquare.gPos = BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER;
            else if( nRow == 0)
                sSquare.gPos = TOP_ROW;
            else if( nRow == num_rows -1 )
                sSquare.gPos = BOTTOM_ROW;
            else if( nColumn == 0)
                sSquare.gPos = LEFT_COLUMN;
            else if( nColumn == num_columns - 1)
                sSquare.gPos = RIGHT_COLUMN;

            vSquareVec[nCurrArrayPoint] = sSquare;

            if( nRow == 0  || nColumn == 0 ||  
                nColumn == num_columns - 1 || nRow == num_rows -1 )
            {
                sSquare.bIsFenced = true;

                vSquareVec[nCurrArrayPoint] = sSquare;

                pair<int,int> p1(nCurrArrayPoint, nCurrentSqHeight);

                qPerimeter.push(p1);
            }
        }
    }

    nCurrWaterLvl = qPerimeter.top().second;

    while( !qPerimeter.empty() )
    {
        pair<int,int> PerimPos = qPerimeter.top();
        qPerimeter.pop();

        if( !vSquareVec[PerimPos.first].bIsVisited )
        {
            if( vSquareVec[PerimPos.first].nHeight > nCurrWaterLvl )
                nCurrWaterLvl = vSquareVec[PerimPos.first].nHeight;

            vSquareVec[PerimPos.first].bIsFlooding = true;
            qFlooding.push(PerimPos);

            while( !qFlooding.empty() )
            {
                pair<int,int> FloodPos = qFlooding.front();
                qFlooding.pop();
                nDepth = nCurrWaterLvl - vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].nHeight;

                if( nDepth >= 0)
                {
                    vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].bIsVisited = true;
                    pair<int,int> newFloodPos;
                    switch(vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].gPos)
                    {
                    case TOP_LEFT_CORNER:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case TOP_RIGHT_CORNER:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case TOP_ROW:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case BOTTOM_ROW:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case LEFT_COLUMN:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case RIGHT_COLUMN:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1 ].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case FREE:
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - 1].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first + num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }
                        if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsVisited && 
                            !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding)
                        {
                            vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].bIsFlooding = true;
                            newFloodPos.first = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nPos;
                            newFloodPos.second = vSquareVec[FloodPos.first - num_rows].nHeight;
                            qFlooding.push(newFloodPos);
                        }

                        nTotalContained += nDepth;

                        break;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].bIsFlooding = false;
                    if( !vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].bIsFenced )
                    {
                        vSquareVec[FloodPos.first].bIsFenced = true;
                        qPerimeter.push(FloodPos);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return nTotalContained;
    }
```

All I'm finding is the top,bottom, left and right square heights.

Currently I'm stuck trying to figure out out how to get the total volume knowing that water will spill over to squares if they are smaller in height. The more that I look at this the more I think that it should be done recursively but can't find a way to implement it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Not looking for the answer just for a push into the right direction into what I need to do.

Comment: Interesting, despite all appearances, I'd call this a path-finding problem.

Comment: From each square, find the path from that square to an edge, where you minimize the height of the highest square you cross. Each square holds water equal to the height of the highest square it's path crossed minus it's starting height. Then sum those for an answer. Of course, that's all theory, There's far easier/faster/better designs for doing this in a practical manner.

Comment: Yea my whole thought process behind it is very similar to what you are talking about.

Comment: Actually had this as an interview question a bit back.  Not an easy problem to try and white board :)

Answer (score 3):

Fun question, with many varied solutions.  I've been thinking about it this afternoon and I would go for something like flood-fill with a priority queue (min-heap, perhaps).  Let's call it the `fence`.

You'll also want to keep track of which items have been visited.  Mark all items as unvisited, initially.

Start off by adding all points around the perimeter of your grid to the `fence`.

Now you loop like so:

Pop the front item from the `fence`.  You have selected one of the lowest points on the perimeter.

- If the item has been visited, discard it and loop again.
- If it's unvisited, its height becomes your new water level only if it is greater than the current water level.

You now do a flood-fill from that point.  You can do this recursively (depth-first), but I will discuss this using an unordered queue (breadth-first).  Let's call this queue the `flood`.  You start by pushing the item onto `flood`.

Flooding then goes like this:  Loop until there are no items remaining in `flood`...

- Pop an item from `flood`
- If it is already visited, ignore it and loop again.
- If the item height is less than or equal to the current water level, compute the height difference and add that to your total volume.  Mark the item as visited, then add all unvisited neighbours to `flood`.
- If the item height is greater than the current water level, just add it to `fence`.  You'll want to have a way to tell whether the item is already in `fence` - you don't want to add it again.  Maybe you can extend your 'visited' flags to cope with this.

And that's it.  Admittedly it was just a thought experiment while I lay around feeling hungover and seedy, but I reckon it's good.

---

As you requested...  Some pseudocode.

Initial setup:

```
## Clear flags.  Note I've added a 'flooding' flag
for each item in map
    item.visited <- false     # true means item has had its water depth added
    item.fenced <- false      # true means item is in the fence queue
    item.flooding <- false    # true means item is in the flooding queue
end

## Set up perimeter
for each item on edge of map (top, left, right, bottom)
    push item onto fence
end

waterlevel <- 0
total <- 0
```

Now the main chunk of the algorithm

```
while fence has items
    item <- pop item from fence
    if item.visited = true then loop again

    ## Update water level
    if item.height > waterlevel then waterlevel = item.height

    ## Flood-fill item using current water level
    push item onto flood
    item.flooding <- true

    while flood has items
        item <- pop item from flood
        depth <- waterlevel - item.height

        if depth >= 0 then
            # Item is at or below water level.  Add its depth to total.
            total <- total + depth
            item.visited <- true

            # Consider all immediate neighbours of item.
            for each neighbour of item
                if neighbour.visited = false then
                    if neighbour.flooding = false then
                        push neighbour onto flood
                        neighbour.flooding <- true
                    end
                end
            end
        else
            # Item is above water
            item.flooding <- false
            if item.fenced = false then
                push item onto fence
                item.fenced <- true
            end
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: So if I'm following this correctly after the first item is popped off fence every other square will go through the flooding process?

Comment: I don't quite get your question, but I guess the answer is 'yes' -- eventually.  It works by flooding each level in succession from the edge (which is zero).  If there is a way for water to escape higher levels, the flood-filling will find it.  I implemented this yesterday and it worked for a reasonably complicated case.  Because you always push newly encountered items onto the fence, you guarantee that all grid positions will be examined.

Comment: Note that my answer is a little wrong - you only mark the item as visited in the first case (where you are checking its neighbours) -- I will edit to correct that.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you also have to check the 'visited' status while flooding, because one node might be in there several times as a different neighbour.

Comment: Hey @TCoder how did you get on with this method?  I chucked some ASTER terrain data at it last night for fun - being a Kiwi, I selected the Southern Alps and glaciers around Mount Cook in New Zealand.  My unoptimized solution using ordinary C++ containers took just over 3 seconds to process a 3601x3601 image.  I'm doing more calculation than I need to, because I'm stamping events in order to animate the filling process.  When I have something cool to show I'll post a video =)

Comment: I'm still a little confused with how you are doing the looping here. Did you loop through all the items in fence first and then continue with the flood loop or do you loop through the items in fence while you are looping through the items in flood? If you have some psuedo code to show what you mean it will help out tons.

Comment: I added pseudocode so you can see better what I mean.  It should make a lot more sense.  Hope I got it right.  You'll notice I added an extra flag, which I've found helpful.  I implemented this in C++ with just `priority_queue` and `queue`, but it might be loads faster if you use a fixed-size circular buffer instead of `queue` (and maybe your own min-heap).  However, you should get it going with basic tools to begin with.

Comment: K i updated with my code trying to follow your puesdo code. Ignore the huge switch statement and what not because i just want to get it done before i go to optimize it. With the board '{2,2,2},
       {2,-1,1},
       {2,2,2}' it gives a result of 4 when it needs to be 2.

Comment: Ok @paddy not sure what is wrong with the code but if i had to guess it with 'nCurrWaterLvl' and 'nDepth'. Dont think its taking into account any water that touches an edge, if that edge is lower all the water that is contained in that space will spill over the edge to become even.

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong.  First, you're not using a priority queue for the perimeter.  This is an absolute requirement.  Any time you pop an item it must be the one with minimum height.  Second, you should not store copies of `Square` in your queues.  You should reference into your `vSquareVec`, either with pointers or array indices.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to take more than simply calculating volume.

According to the examples you posted, you have test for *containment* first, then worry about the volume of the container.

I suggest determining whether or not there is a closed polygon in the board.
If the polygon is closed, determine its area.
The height used for volume calculation will be the minimum height of all the bounding walls.
Finally, the volume will be the minimal height multiplied by the area of the polygon.

Research on the web for algorithms on determining a closed polygon based on a vector of vertices or line segments.

Comment: (1) you overlooked the height of the contained squares, I beleive there are other possible heights besides 0 and 1. (2) You don't mention multiple enclosed polygons (3) I think there's simpler solutions that are more accurate

Comment: The values inside of p_data hold both positive and negative values.

Comment: @TCoder please edit the question to say that to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute-force-ish but would probably work.

You might try to conceptually break the board into layers for instance:

```
-------------------------
0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 |-1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
-------------------------
```

Looking at just the lowest layer. Assuming -1 is the bottom, the board would look like this:

```
-------------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 |-1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
-------------------------
```

For each square, determine if there exists a square to the left, right, top and bottom that all have a greater value. In this case we count 1.

Then move to the next layer, filling in the "holes" in the last layer.

```
-------------------------
0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
-------------------------
```

Rinse, repeat. In this layer we count 4 giving us a total of 5.

```
-------------------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
-------------------------
```

Top layer obviously has none and we're done.

In pseudo code:

```
for each layer l in layers
   for each square in l
      if there exists a square left, right, top and bottom with higher value
          count the square.
```

**Edit**

Of course since there is something seriously wrong with me, when I woke up this morning the first thing I thought of was this problem and immediately broke my solution.

Let's make one change to the example:

```
-------------------------
0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 |-1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1
-------------------------
                    ^
```

Open a hole to the outside. With the current algorithm we would get a solution of 4 which is obviously wrong.

To fix this we need to implement a back tracking algorithm.

Instead of looking anywhere to the left, right, top and bottom for a higher value, we check just the immediately adjacent squares. If any are at the same height we need to visit that square as well and perform the check again. If we find our way to the outside then the original square (and subsequently all the visited squares) fail. If we hit a dead end, then all the visited squares can be counted.

With this modification we would get the correct result of 3.

Comment: In feel like this can be time consuming if large 2d arrays with big heights are put into the function. Essentially its just looping through the entire array for every number between the lowest and highest height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of working code: the basic idea is slicing the board horizontally into levels, and determining the volume each level can hold (complexity O(x * y * z)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

// The Cell structure for each level
struct Cell
{
    unsigned char height; // either 0 or 1
    bool visited; // we only visit the cells that have height of 0
};

// The recursive function that visits a cell, accumulate the water volume (or if leaked due to being at the border, reset the values); it also
// looks to its 4 adjacent cells (if valid) recursively.
// Note that the top level function actually attempts to visit *all* the "connected" cells (and mark them as visited, so they will not be visited again)
// From the top level, the cells are thus visited in "chunks" (as long as they are connected)
void VisitCell(Cell* one_level_cells, unsigned short a_w, unsigned short a_h, unsigned short w, unsigned short h, unsigned __int64* sum, bool* leaked)
{
    Cell& cell = one_level_cells[h * a_w + w];
    if (cell.height == 0 && !cell.visited)
    {
        cell.visited = true;
        if (w == 0 || w + 1 == a_w || h == 0 || h + 1 == a_h)
        {
            // I am at the border while I am not guarding the water, the water for this "chunk" is then leaked!
            *leaked = true;
            *sum = 0;
        }

        if (!*leaked)
        {
            // potentially increment the volume, until it's detected leaked at some point
            ++*sum;
        }

        if (w < a_w - 1)    VisitCell(one_level_cells, a_w, a_h, w+1, h, sum, leaked);
        if (w > 0)          VisitCell(one_level_cells, a_w, a_h, w-1, h, sum, leaked);
        if (h < a_h - 1)    VisitCell(one_level_cells, a_w, a_h, w, h+1, sum, leaked);
        if (h > 0)          VisitCell(one_level_cells, a_w, a_h, w, h-1, sum, leaked);
    }
}

//@param int const * const unsigned short *a_board - argument representing the NxM board.
//@param unsigned short a_w - argument representing the width of the board
//@param unsigned short a_h - argument representing the height of the board
//@return - unsigned __int64 - the volume of water the board retains

// complexity: O(a_w * a_h * max_height)
unsigned __int64 CalculateVolume(const unsigned short *a_board, unsigned short a_w, unsigned short a_h)
{
    if (!a_board || a_w < 3 || a_h < 3)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Basic algorithm: slice the board horizontally into as many levels as the maximum height of the board
    // for each sliced level, determine the water volume cubed so far, and the total volume is the sum of the volume of the individual level
    unsigned __int32 n = a_w * a_h;
    unsigned short max_height = 0;
    for (unsigned __int32 i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (max_height < a_board[i])
        {
            max_height = a_board[i];
        }
    }
    unsigned short *board = new unsigned short[n];
    memcpy(board, a_board, n * sizeof(unsigned short));
    Cell* one_level_cells = new Cell[n];
    unsigned __int64 total_volume = 0;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < max_height; ++i)
    {
        // form a new current level of cells (and update the copy of the board accordingly)
        unsigned __int64 volume_this_level = 0;
        for (unsigned __int32 j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (board[j] > 0)
            {
                --board[j];
                one_level_cells[j].height = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                one_level_cells[j].height = 0;
            }
            one_level_cells[j].visited = false;
        }

        // visit all the cells within the current level
        // we mark the cells after being visited, and the cells are visited in "chunks" when they are "connected" together
        // so effectively, most of the top level cell visiting would return immediately, rather than trying to revisit the cells again and again
        for (unsigned short h = 0; h < a_h; ++h)
        {
            for (unsigned short w = 0; w < a_w; ++w)
            {
                unsigned __int64 sum = 0;
                bool leaked = false;
                // NB: the top level function here will attempt to cover *all* the connected cells at the current level (in the recursion)
                // so even though we are still iterating through all the cells at the top level, most of them should find that the cell has been visited
                // so the sum here is actually a "chunked" sum in the perception of the top level cells
                VisitCell(one_level_cells, a_w, a_h, w, h, &sum, &leaked);
                volume_this_level += sum;
            }
        }

        total_volume += volume_this_level;
    }

    delete[] one_level_cells;
    delete[] board;

    return total_volume;
}

int main()
{
    // feel free to play with this board
    unsigned short board[] = {
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2,
        2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    };
    printf("Volume: %lld\n", CalculateVolume(board, 8, 8));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is python(2.7) version of the pseudocode by @paddy .Hope this will help someone .

```
import heapq
block =[
1, 2, 3,
4 ,2,6,
7, 0,5,
11,15, 13,
14,15,16,
1,0,1,
1,1,1]
cmax =3; 
rmax =7;
items =[]
fence = []
flood = []
waterlevel = 0
total = 0
class Item(object):
    visited = False
    fenced = False
    flooding = False
    height= 0
    index = 0
i=0
## initializing blocks
for val in block:    
    item =  Item();
    item.height = val
    item.index = i
    i+=1
    items.append((item.height,item))
## find out the edges  
for i in range (cmax):
    heapq.heappush(fence, items[i])
    heapq.heappush(fence, items[i+(rmax-1)*cmax])
    print items[i][1].height,items[i+(rmax-1)*cmax][1].height

for i in range(1,rmax-1):
    heapq.heappush(fence, items[cmax*i])
    heapq.heappush(fence, items[cmax*i+(cmax-1)])
    print items[cmax*i][1].height,items[cmax*i+(cmax-1)][1].height

## get neighbour
def get_neighbour(i):
    c= i%cmax
    r= i//cmax
    neighbour = []
    if (c != 0):
        neighbour.append(items[r*cmax+c-1])
    if (c != (cmax -1)):
        neighbour.append(items[r*cmax+c+1])
    if (r != 0):
        neighbour.append(items[(r-1)*cmax+c])
    if (r != (rmax -1)):    
        neighbour.append(items[(r+1)*cmax+c])
    return neighbour



while (len(fence)>0):
    item = heapq.heappop(fence)
    if(item[1].visited):
        continue
    if (item[1].height > waterlevel):
        waterlevel = item[1].height
    heapq.heappush(flood,item)
    item[1].flooding = True
    while(len(flood)>0):
        fitem = heapq.heappop(flood)
        depth = waterlevel - fitem[1].height
        if (depth >= 0):
            total += depth
            fitem[1].visited = True
            neighbour = get_neighbour(fitem[1].index)
            for nitem in neighbour:
                if nitem[1].visited == False :
                    if nitem[1].flooding == False :
                        heapq.heappush(flood,nitem)
                        nitem[1].flooding = True
        else:
            fitem[1].flooding = False
            if fitem[1].fenced == False:
                heapq.heappush(fence,fitem)
                fitem[1].fenced = True
print total
```