# The Maximum Volume of Trapped Rain Water in 3D

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

A classic algorithm question in 2D version is typically described as

Given n non-negative integers representing an elevation map where the width of each bar is 1, compute how much water it is able to trap after raining.

For example, Given the input

```
[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]
```

the return value would be

```
6
```

[image]

The algorithm that I used to solve the above 2D problem is

```
int trapWaterVolume2D(vector<int> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    vector<int> leftmost(n, 0), rightmost(n, 0);

    //left exclusive scan, O(n), the highest bar to the left each point
    int leftMaxSoFar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        leftmost[i] = leftMaxSoFar;
        if (A[i] > leftMaxSoFar) leftMaxSoFar = A[i];
    }


    //right exclusive scan, O(n), the highest bar to the right each point
    int rightMaxSoFar = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        rightmost[i] = rightMaxSoFar;
        if (A[i] > rightMaxSoFar) rightMaxSoFar = A[i];
    }

    // Summation, O(n)
    int vol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vol += max(0, min(leftmost[i], rightmost[i]) - A[i]);
    }
    return vol;
}
```

My Question is how to make the above algorithm extensible to the 3D version of the problem, to compute the maximum of water trapped in real-world 3D terrain. i.e. To implement

```
int trapWaterVolume3D(vector<vector<int> > A);
```

Sample graph:

[image]

We know the elevation at each (x, y) point and the goal is to compute the maximum volume of water that can be trapped in the shape. Any thoughts and references are welcome.

Comment: It is the same algorithm as used to compute the fracture in metals.

Comment: This question is probably also related to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033555/tips-on-finding-the-volume-of-water-in-a-3d-chess-board/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For each point on the terrain consider all paths from that point to the border of the terrain. The level of water would be the minimum of the maximum heights of the points of those paths. To find it we need to perform a slightly modified Dijkstra's algorithm, filling the water level matrix starting from the border.

```
For every point on the border set the water level to the point height
For every point not on the border set the water level to infinity
Put every point on the border into the set of active points
While the set of active points is not empty:
    Select the active point P with minimum level
    Remove P from the set of active points
    For every point Q adjacent to P:
        Level(Q) = max(Height(Q), min(Level(Q), Level(P)))
        If Level(Q) was changed:
            Add Q to the set of active points
```

Answer (score 6):

user3290797's "slightly modified Dijkstra algorithm" is closer to Prim's algorithm than Dijkstra's. In minimum spanning tree terms, we prepare a graph with one vertex per tile, one vertex for the outside, and edges with weights equal to the maximum height of their two adjoining tiles (the outside has height "minus infinity").

Given a path in this graph to the outside vertex, the maximum weight of an edge in the path is the height that the water has to reach in order to escape along that path. The relevant property of a minimum spanning tree is that, for every pair of vertices, the maximum weight of an edge in the path in the spanning tree is the minimum possible among all paths between those vertices. The minimum spanning tree thus describes the most economical escape paths for water, and the water heights can be extracted in linear time with one traversal.

As a bonus, since the graph is planar, there's a linear-time algorithm for computing the minimum spanning tree, consisting of alternating Boruvka passes and simplifications. This improves on the O(n log n) running time of Prim.

Comment: Well, in the Dijkstra's algorithm the next vertex is selected based on the cost of the path to that vertex (just like in mine), and in the Prim's algorithm the next edge is selected based on its own cost; that's why I think my algorithm is more similar to Dijkstra's than to Prim's.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved using the Priority-Flood algorithm. It's been discovered and published a number of times over the past few decades (and again by other people answering this question), though the specific variant you're looking for is not, to my knowledge, in the literature.

You can find a review paper of the algorithm and its variants [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300413001337). Since that paper was published an even faster variant has been discovered ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300416300553)), as well as methods to perform this calculation on datasets of trillions of cells ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300416301704)). A method for selectively breaching low/narrow divides is discussed [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hyp.10648/abstract). Contact me if you'd like copies of any of these papers.

I have a repository [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/Barnes2013-Depressions) with many of the above variants; additional implementations can be found [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/richdem/tree/1788b9146c4a6abe3aadf737571bba744505f79d/include/richdem/depressions).

A simple script to calculate volume using the RichDEM library is as follows:

```cpp
#include "richdem/common/version.hpp"
#include "richdem/common/router.hpp"
#include "richdem/depressions/Lindsay2016.hpp"
#include "richdem/common/Array2D.hpp"

/**
  @brief  Calculates the volume of depressions in a DEM
  @author Richard Barnes (rbarnes@umn.edu)

    Priority-Flood starts on the edges of the DEM and then works its way inwards
    using a priority queue to determine the lowest cell which has a path to the
    edge. The neighbours of this cell are added to the priority queue if they
    are higher. If they are lower, then they are members of a depression and the
    elevation of the flooding minus the elevation of the DEM times the cell area
    is the flooded volume of the cell. The cell is flooded, total volume
    tracked, and the neighbors are then added to a "depressions" queue which is
    used to flood depressions. Cells which are higher than a depression being
    filled are added to the priority queue. In this way, depressions are filled
    without incurring the expense of the priority queue.

  @param[in,out]  &elevations   A grid of cell elevations

  @pre
    1. **elevations** contains the elevations of every cell or a value _NoData_
       for cells not part of the DEM. Note that the _NoData_ value is assumed to
       be a negative number less than any actual data value.

  @return
    Returns the total volume of the flooded depressions.

  @correctness
    The correctness of this command is determined by inspection. (TODO)
*/
template <class elev_t>
double improved_priority_flood_volume(const Array2D<elev_t> &elevations){
  GridCellZ_pq<elev_t> open;
  std::queue<GridCellZ<elev_t> > pit;
  uint64_t processed_cells = 0;
  uint64_t pitc            = 0;
  ProgressBar progress;

  std::cerr<<"\nPriority-Flood (Improved) Volume"<<std::endl;
  std::cerr<<"\nC Barnes, R., Lehman, C., Mulla, D., 2014. Priority-flood: An optimal depression-filling and watershed-labeling algorithm for digital elevation models. Computers & Geosciences 62, 117–127. doi:10.1016/j.cageo.2013.04.024"<<std::endl;

  std::cerr<<"p Setting up boolean flood array matrix..."<<std::endl;
  //Used to keep track of which cells have already been considered
  Array2D<int8_t> closed(elevations.width(),elevations.height(),false);

  std::cerr<<"The priority queue will require approximately "
           <<(elevations.width()*2+elevations.height()*2)*((long)sizeof(GridCellZ<elev_t>))/1024/1024
           <<"MB of RAM."
           <<std::endl;

  std::cerr<<"p Adding cells to the priority queue..."<<std::endl;

  //Add all cells on the edge of the DEM to the priority queue
  for(int x=0;x<elevations.width();x++){
    open.emplace(x,0,elevations(x,0) );
    open.emplace(x,elevations.height()-1,elevations(x,elevations.height()-1) );
    closed(x,0)=true;
    closed(x,elevations.height()-1)=true;
  }
  for(int y=1;y<elevations.height()-1;y++){
    open.emplace(0,y,elevations(0,y)  );
    open.emplace(elevations.width()-1,y,elevations(elevations.width()-1,y) );
    closed(0,y)=true;
    closed(elevations.width()-1,y)=true;
  }

  double volume = 0;

  std::cerr<<"p Performing the improved Priority-Flood..."<<std::endl;
  progress.start( elevations.size() );
  while(open.size()>0 || pit.size()>0){
    GridCellZ<elev_t> c;
    if(pit.size()>0){
      c=pit.front();
      pit.pop();
    } else {
      c=open.top();
      open.pop();
    }
    processed_cells++;

    for(int n=1;n<=8;n++){
      int nx=c.x+dx[n];
      int ny=c.y+dy[n];
      if(!elevations.inGrid(nx,ny)) continue;
      if(closed(nx,ny))
        continue;

      closed(nx,ny)=true;
      if(elevations(nx,ny)<=c.z){
        if(elevations(nx,ny)<c.z){
          ++pitc;
          volume += (c.z-elevations(nx,ny))*std::abs(elevations.getCellArea());
        }
        pit.emplace(nx,ny,c.z);
      } else
        open.emplace(nx,ny,elevations(nx,ny));
    }
    progress.update(processed_cells);
  }
  std::cerr<<"t Succeeded in "<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(1)<<progress.stop()<<" s"<<std::endl;
  std::cerr<<"m Cells processed = "<<processed_cells<<std::endl;
  std::cerr<<"m Cells in pits = "  <<pitc           <<std::endl;

  return volume;
}

template<class T>
int PerformAlgorithm(std::string analysis, Array2D<T> elevations){
  elevations.loadData();

  std::cout<<"Volume: "<<improved_priority_flood_volume(elevations)<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::string analysis = PrintRichdemHeader(argc,argv);

  if(argc!=2){
    std::cerr<<argv[0]<<" <Input>"<<std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  return PerformAlgorithm(argv[1],analysis);
}
```

It should be straight-forward to adapt this to whatever 2d array format you are using

In pseudocode, the following is equivalent to the foregoing:

```
Let PQ be a priority-queue which always pops the cell of lowest elevation
Let Closed be a boolean array initially set to False
Let Volume = 0
Add all the border cells to PQ.
For each border cell, set the cell's entry in Closed to True.
While PQ is not empty:
  Select the top cell from PQ, call it C.
  Pop the top cell from PQ.
  For each neighbor N of C:
    If Closed(N):
      Continue
    If Elevation(N)<Elevation(C):
      Volume += (Elevation(C)-Elevation(N))*Area
      Add N to PQ, but with Elevation(C)
    Else:
      Add N to PQ with Elevation(N)
    Set Closed(N)=True
```

Comment: I've seen [Python implementation](http://www.jianshu.com/p/540ee7ec725b) of the algorithm described in the pseudo-code in your answer (text in Chinese). Here's a [slightly modified version](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729857/23044) (text in Russian)

Comment: @Richard, I would like to study and understand this algorithm, would you please share copy of the paper? rmp [et] outlook.in

Answer (score 3):

This problem is very close to the construction of the [morphological watershed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)) of a grayscale image.

One approach is as follows (flooding process):

- sort all pixels by increasing elevation.
- work incrementally, by increasing elevations, assigning labels to the pixels per catchment basin.
- for a new elevation level, you need to label a new set of pixels:

  - Some have no labeled 
    neighbor, they form a local minimum configuration and begin a new catchment basin.
  - Some have only neighbors with the same label, they can be labeled similarly (they extend a catchment basin).
  - Some have neighbors with different labels. They do not belong to a specific catchment basin and they define the watershed lines.

You will need to enhance the standard watershed algorithm to be able to compute the volume of water. You can do that by determining the maximum water level in each basin and deduce the ground height on every pixel. The water level in a basin is given by the elevation of the lowest watershed pixel around it.

You can act every time you discover a watershed pixel: if a neighboring basin has not been assigned a level yet, that basin can stand the current level without leaking.

Answer (score 3):

In order to accomplish tapping water problem in 3D i.e., to calculate the maximum volume of trapped rain water you can do something like this:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10

int new2d[MAX][MAX];
int dp[MAX][MAX],visited[MAX][MAX];


int dx[] = {1,0,-1,0};
int dy[] = {0,-1,0,1};


int boundedBy(int i,int j,int k,int in11,int in22)
{
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=in11 || j>=in22)
        return 0;

    if(new2d[i][j]>k)
        return new2d[i][j];

    if(visited[i][j])   return INT_MAX;

    visited[i][j] = 1;

    int r = INT_MAX;
    for(int dir = 0 ; dir<4 ; dir++)
    {
        int nx = i + dx[dir];
        int ny = j + dy[dir];
        r = min(r,boundedBy(nx,ny,k,in11,in22));
    }
    return r;
}

void mark(int i,int j,int k,int in1,int in2)
{
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=in1 || j>=in2)
        return;

    if(new2d[i][j]>=k)
        return;

    if(visited[i][j])   return ;

    visited[i][j] = 1;

    for(int dir = 0;dir<4;dir++)
    {
        int nx = i + dx[dir];
        int ny = j + dy[dir];
        mark(nx,ny,k,in1,in2);
    }
    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j],k);
}

struct node
{
    int i,j,key;
    node(int x,int y,int k)
    {
        i = x;
        j = y;
        key = k;
    }
};

bool compare(node a,node b)
{
    return a.key>b.key;
}
vector<node> store;

int getData(int input1, int input2, int input3[])
 {

  int row=input1;
  int col=input2;
  int temp=0;
    int count=0;

        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                if(count==(col*row)) 
                break;
            new2d[i][j]=input3[count];
            count++;
            }
        }

  store.clear();
  for(int i = 0;i<input1;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<input2;j++)
            {
                store.push_back(node(i,j,new2d[i][j]));
            }
        }
   memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));

        sort(store.begin(),store.end(),compare);

       for(int i = 0;i<store.size();i++)
        {
            memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));

            int aux = boundedBy(store[i].i,store[i].j,store[i].key,input1,input2);
            if(aux>store[i].key)
            {

                 memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));
                 mark(store[i].i,store[i].j,aux,input1,input2);
            }

        }

        long long result =0 ;

        for(int i = 0;i<input1;i++)
        {

            for(int j = 0;j<input2;j++)
            {
                result = result + max(0,dp[i][j]-new2d[i][j]);
            }
        }

      return result;

 }


int main()
{
    cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
       int n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
       int inp3[n*m];
        store.clear();

            for(int j = 0;j<n*m;j++)
            {
                cin>>inp3[j];

            }

  int k = getData(n,m,inp3);
       cout<<k;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code for the same-

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n,count=0,a[100];
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       cin>>a[i];
   }
   for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++)
   {
       ///computing left most largest and Right most largest element of array;
       int leftmax=0;
       int rightmax=0;
       ///left most largest
       for(int j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
       {
           if(a[j]>leftmax)
           {
              leftmax=a[j];
           }
       }
       ///rightmost largest

       for(int k=i+1;k<=n-1;k++)
       {
           if(a[k]>rightmax)
           {
              rightmax=a[k];
           }
       }
       ///computing hight of the water contained-

       int x=(min(rightmax,leftmax)-a[i]);
       if(x>0)
       {
           count=count+x;
       }

   }
   cout<<count;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is about extending the algorithm to 3D.

Comment: Seconding Blastfurnace in assuming `make … extensible` is an unfortunate wording where *extend* is wanted: this does not answer the question. Good of you to present commented code (have a look at conventions and tools - [dogygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html), for one), but with a question not mentioning a programming language, you should do so. Code only answers are frowned upon: Please summarise your idea/approach (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Solution(object):
def trapRainWater(self, heightMap):
    """
    :type heightMap: List[List[int]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    m = len(heightMap)
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    n = len(heightMap[0])
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    visited = [[False for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
    from Queue import PriorityQueue
    q = PriorityQueue()
    for i in range(m):
        visited[i][0] = True
        q.put([heightMap[i][0],i,0])
        visited[i][n-1] = True
        q.put([heightMap[i][n-1],i,n-1])
    for j in range(1, n-1):
        visited[0][j] = True
        q.put([heightMap[0][j],0,j])
        visited[m-1][j] = True
        q.put([heightMap[m-1][j],m-1,j])
    S = 0
    while not q.empty():
        cell = q.get()
        for (i, j) in [(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]:
            x = cell[1] + i
            y = cell[2] + j
            if x in range(m) and y in range(n) and not visited[x][y]:
                S += max(0, cell[0] - heightMap[x][y])   # how much water at the cell
                q.put([max(heightMap[x][y],cell[0]),x,y])
                visited[x][y] = True
    return S
```

Comment: add some description