# Calculate trapped water in a structure

Tags: python, performance, optimization, out-of-memory, space-complexity

Supposed my input is `[1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]` . Then we can create a
structure like this:

```
...X...
.X.X...
.X.X..X
.XXX.XX
XXXXXXX
1425123
```

When water is poured over the top at all places and allowed to runoff,
it will remain trapped at the 'O' locations:

```
...X...
.XOX...
.XOXOOX
.XXXOXX
XXXXXXX
1425123
```

we have to find a total number of trapped 'O' in a given list.

My program is able to give me the correct output but when I run it
against different test cases, it gives me a `memory error`. Is there any way I can reduce the `space complexity` of this program?

```
def answer(heights):
    row = len(heights)
    col = max(heights)
    sum = 0
    matrix = [['X' for j in range(i)] for i in heights]
    for i in range(col):
        rainWater = []
        for j in range(row):
            try:
                rainWater.append(matrix[j][i])
            except IndexError:
                rainWater.append('0')
        sum += ''.join(rainWater).strip('0').count('0')
    return sum

print answer([1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

The list array will have at least 1 element and at most 9000 elements. Each element will have a value of at least 1, and at most 100000.

```
Inputs:
    (int list) heights = [1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]

Output:
    (int) 5

Inputs:
    (int list) heights = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

Output:
    (int) 0
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: You don't need to create the matrix at all, what you need is a simple list of heights then just analyze the high and lows. Its not possible for any water to stay in the first or last spot so you can work thru the rest. This will solve the space issue and most likely run faster.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am working on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved in linear time with linear memory requirements in the following way:

```
def answer(heights):
    minLeft = [0] * len(heights)
    left = 0
    for idx, h in enumerate(heights):
        if left < h:
            left = h
        minLeft[idx] = left

    minRight = [0] * len(heights)
    right = 0
    for idx, h in enumerate(heights[::-1]):
        if right < h:
            right = h
        minRight[len(heights) - 1 - idx] = right

    water = 0
    for h, l, r in zip(heights, minLeft, minRight):
        water += min([l, r]) - h

    return water
```

The arrays `minLeft` and `minRight` contain the highest level at which water can be supported at a place in the array if there was a wall of infinite size on the right or left side respectively. Then at each index, total water that can be contained is the *minimum of the water levels supported by the left and the right side* - *height of the floor*.

---

This question deals with this problem in higher dimension (relating it to the *Watershed problem* in image processing): [The Maximum Volume of Trapped Rain Water in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818044/the-maximum-volume-of-trapped-rain-water-in-3d)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The code's in c#. O(N) time, O(1) space. Using two pointers, and 2 integer variable to track. Can't figure out a more optimized way for this question.

```
     public int Trap(int[] height) {
    if(height == null || height.Length == 0)
      return 0;
    int max = 0;
    int vol = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = height.Length - 1;

    while(left<= right)
    {
        if(height[left] < height[right])
        {
            max = Math.Max(max,height[left]);
            vol = vol + (max-height[left]);
            left++;
        }
        else
        {
            max = Math.Max(max,height[right]);
            vol = vol + (max-height[right]);
            right--;
        }
    }
    return vol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem with a single loop (the following example is written in Java):

```
public static int trapw(int[] check) {
    int sum = 0, ml = 0, mr = 0, clen = 0;

    if ((clen = check.length-1) <= 1)
        return 0;

    int[] r = new int[clen+1];

    for (int k = 0, lidx = clen; k <= clen; k++, lidx = clen - k) {
        ml = Math.max(ml, check[k]); mr = Math.max(mr, check[lidx]);
        if (k < lidx) {
            r[k] = ml; r[lidx] = mr;
        } else if (lidx == k) {
            // Middlepoint
            r[k] = Math.min(ml, mr); sum += Math.max(r[k] - check[k], 0);
        } else {
            r[k] = Math.max((Math.min(ml, r[k]) - check[k]), 0);
            r[lidx] = Math.max((Math.min(mr, r[lidx]) - check[lidx]), 0);
            sum += r[k] + r[lidx];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```