# Find height of water needed to flood a landscape to a certain volume

Tags: c++, algorithm

I recently came across an algorithmic problem where the objective was to compute the height of the water level needed to produce a certain amount of flooding in a city with buildings that each have width 1.

It is somewhat similar to the two-dimensional rainwater-trapping problem described here:

[The Maximum Volume of Trapped Rain Water in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818044/the-maximum-volume-of-trapped-rain-water-in-3d)

However, in my problem, we count water above the buildings in addition to the water trapped between buildings. For example, take this problem instance:

```
volume needed: 60
number of buildings: 3
heights of buildings: 30 40 20
```

This means that we have to compute the water level needed so that a city with buildings of height 30, 40, and 20, in that order, has a flood of water with a volume of at least 60.

```
^
|
50       |~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|        |             |        
40       |    -----    |                
|        |    |   |    |                 
30       -----|   |    |               
|        |   ||   |    |        
20       |   ||   |-----
|        |   ||   ||   |
10       |   ||   ||   |
|        |   ||   ||   |
.----------1----2----3---------->
```

In this case the result would be 50, as the water level needs to be at height 50 so that the volume of water between and above the buildings is at least 60. Here, the flooding above each building is 20, 10, and 30, adding up to exactly 60.

My attempt performs poorly both in time and correctness:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int v;
  int n;
  cin >> v >> n;

  vector<int> altitudes;
  int count = 0;
  int altitude;

  while (count < n) {
    cin >> altitude;
    altitudes.push_back(altitude);
    count++;
  }

  sort(altitudes.begin(), altitudes.end());

  int vtemp = 0;
  int i = 1;
  int h = altitudes[0];

  while (vtemp < v && i < n) {
    h++;
    if (h == altitudes[i]) {
      i++;
    }
    vtemp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      vtemp += h - altitudes[j];
    }
  }

  cout << h << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do not ask on [Programming puzzles & Code gold](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You're not really asking people to review undocumented code, are you? That said, write the algorithm in a natural language first, so that any human being can perform the calculation. Then, use this description as comments on which you base your C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added comments in code to my algorithm.
I tested it on your test data and it works.
The time complexity is O(n log n) because we need to sort builidings.
Without sorting the algorithm works in O(n)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int v;
    int n;
    cin >> v >> n;

    vector<int> altitudes;
    int count = 0;
    int altitude;

    while (count < n) {
        cin >> altitude;
        altitudes.push_back(altitude);
        count++;
    }

    sort(altitudes.begin(), altitudes.end());
//-- changed from here
    int current_level = altitudes[0]; //start from height of the smallest building
    int length = 0;

    while (v > 0)
    {
        ++length; //go to next level
        for (; length < altitudes.size() && altitudes[length] == altitudes[length - 1]; ++length); //find length of current water level

        int height = v / length; //maximum possible height to fill
        if (length < altitudes.size()) //if not all building in use
            height = min(height, altitudes[length] - current_level); //fill with all water (height) or with the difference to next level

        current_level += height; //increase level by height
        v -= height * length; //decrease amount of water

        if (length == altitudes.size() || v < length) //we filled the whole area, or there is no enough water to fill 1 'meter'
            break;
    }

    cout << current_level << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the height from the lowest to the highest, then start filling the lowest until its height is equal to the second lowest, then fill both lowest and second lowest until their height is equal to third lowest and so on until you run out of water.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track when you sort the buildings. This gives us a clearer picture of the layers of water trapped above each building.

For example, say we have buildings of height 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5:

```
     x
x    x
x x  x
xxx xx
xxxxxx
```

Let's flood them with water. This diagram uses 1 to indicate the lowest layer of water, 2 for the second lowest, and so on:

```
44444x
x3333x
x2x22x
xxx1xx
xxxxxx
```

We can traverse the buildings row by row to add up the layers of water until we achieve the required volume. However, this would take `O(nm)` time, where `n` is the number of buildings and `m` is the maximum building height. We can do better.

Let's sort the buildings. Now the heights from left to right are 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5:

```
     x
    xx
   xxx
 xxxxx
xxxxxx
```

Again, let's flood them:

```
44444x
3333xx
222xxx
1xxxxx
xxxxxx
```

Now the water layers are much easier to count. The length of each layer is the number of buildings with the same height plus the length of the previous layer.

This lets us count the layers in `O(n)` time because we scan the building heights once and perform a constant number of operations per building. The cost to sort the buildings is `O(n log n)`. The total cost of `O(n log n + n)` is better than `O(nm)` unless `m` is quite small.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int requiredVolume, n;

  cin >> requiredVolume >> n;
  vector<int> heights;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int height;
    cin >> height;
    heights.push_back(height);
  }

  // Sort the buildings by increasing height.
  sort(heights.begin(), heights.end());

  // Start with the required volume and subtract layers until we reach zero.
  int volume = requiredVolume,
      waterHeight = heights[0],
      layerLength = 0,
      pos = 0;

  while (volume > 0) {
    // Look for the next building that's taller than the current one.
    int seek = pos;
    while (seek < n && heights[seek] == heights[pos]) {
      ++seek;
    }

    // Extend the current water layer.
    layerLength += seek - pos;

    // Calculate the number of layers we would need to reach zero.
    int needLayers = (volume + layerLength - 1) / layerLength;

    // If we're at the tallest building, take all the layers we need.
    // Otherwise, take layers up to the height of the next building.
    int addLayers; 
    if (seek == n) {
      addLayers = needLayers;
    } else {
      addLayers = min(heights[seek] - heights[pos], needLayers);
    }

    volume -= addLayers * layerLength;
    waterHeight += addLayers;

    cout << "with water at height " << waterHeight <<
        ", the volume is " << (requiredVolume - volume) << '\n';

    // Advance to the next building.
    pos = seek;
  }

  cout << "final answer:\n    minimum height = " << waterHeight <<
      ", volume reached = " << (requiredVolume - volume) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

For the problem instance you gave in your question:

```
60 3
30 40 20
```

We get this output:

```
with water at height 30, the volume is 10
with water at height 40, the volume is 30
with water at height 50, the volume is 60
final answer:
    minimum height = 50, volume reached = 60
```

If we want to achieve a volume of at least 11 with the buildings from the example above:

```
11 5
4 2 3 1 2 5
```

We get this:

```
with water at height 2, the volume is 1
with water at height 3, the volume is 4
with water at height 4, the volume is 8
with water at height 5, the volume is 13
final answer:
    minimum height = 5, volume reached = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search on the answer to find the correct height. Guess a height and find the volume above buildings if it is more than desires amount guess lower, if it less than desired amount guess higher. Continue this procedure till you find the correct height.